# Does SpaceX patent its inventions?

Tags: spacex, law

Considering that SpaceX is a private, for-profit company that likes to invent its own solutions, **has SpaceX patented any of its inventions?**

Related questions:

- [Do government space agencies capitalise on selling intellectual property/patents etc](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12438/26446)
- [Would NASA be financially self-sufficient if it could keep all revenues from patents?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25847/26446)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from a series of patent applications related to Starlink antennas, they haven't aggressively sought patents.

A [search of the US patent office application database](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=space%20exploration&FIELD1=AS&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PG01) gives the following hits for patent *applications* credited to SpaceX.

- 20200086602  LASER-PERFORATED METAL HONEYCOMB MATERIAL
- 20190252801  ANTENNA APERTURE IN PHASED ARRAY ANTENNA SYSTEMS
- 20190252800  SELF-MULTIPLEXING ANTENNAS
- 20190252775  PHASED ARRAY ANTENNA SYSTEMS
- 20190252774  ANTENNA-TO-BEAMFORMER ASSIGNMENT AND MAPPING IN PHASED ARRAY ANTENNA SYSTEMS
- 20180093443  LASER-PERFORATED METAL HONEYCOMB MATERIAL AND METHOD OF MANUFACTURING SAME
- 20090007543  Pintle injector tip with active cooling

The [patent collection database shows only two of these](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=space%20exploration&FIELD1=ASNM&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PTXT); I'm guessing the antenna patents, applied for only last year, haven't gotten through the patent pipeline yet.

- 10,486,389    Laser-perforated metal honeycomb material and method of manufacturing same
- 7,503,511 Pintle injector tip with active cooling

A [Business Insider article](https://www.businessinsider.com/elon-musk-patents-2012-11) references an interview for Wired magazine, explaining why they seek so few patents:

> "We have essentially no patents in SpaceX. Our primary long-term competition is in China," said Musk in the interview. "If we published patents, it would be farcical, because the Chinese would just use them as a recipe book."

Comment: This is very different from the car industry in which people stream teardowns on the internet. Space companies utilizing their own innovations (in contrast to licensing patents) are better off sustaining a high rate of innovation and forcing all people familiar with the matter (employees, NASA reviewers, ...) into non-disclosure agreements.

Comment: Big difference in the car industry is when you buy a car, it's yours and you can take whatever tools you like to it.  SpaceX doesn't sell rockets, it sells rides on their rockets.